# Uplink: Hacker Elite gateway upgrade problem

Tags: uplink

I've seen a few similar posts, but never a definitive answer on how to fix this. When I buy a new gateway, I never actually receive it. I get the "wait 24 hours" email, then I get the "your gateway is complete" email that tells me to log out and back in to get it. I've logged out of the agent and the game itself, reloaded, and always see the default gateway in my hardware when I return. I've tried buying a few different gateways, all with the same result. I uninstalled and reinstalled the game, once keeping my save and once wiping it out, and there was no difference. Is there any way to get around this? I really want to play the game, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I haven't played Uplink in a while, but I vaguely remember after buying a gateway, you have to tell it to switch out your current gateway with the one you bought.

Comment: I'll double check tonight, but I don't remember any option to switch my gateway.  When I logout and back in after I get the email that my gateway is ready, it tells me that the new one is installed and I should see its specs on my hardware page.

Comment: Didn't see any option to change the gateway manually.  The emails you get in-game say that you'll automatically be directed to the new gateway and the old one will be dismantled.

Comment: Hmm...are you sure that you aren't actually using the new one? You don't get a faster Gateway when you upgrade, you only get the ability to upgrade, if I remember correctly. So you would have to buy more CPUs and more memory.

Comment: Hah, if that's the case, I will feel dumb.  To the Internets for more research!

Comment: That was it!  Thank you, NovaSword!  Can you post it as an answer so I can verify it?

Comment: Done, feel free to make suggestions on how I could improve my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you buy a new gateway, you don't get any new benefits. You still have the same benefits as before.

Here is your default gateway:

[image: Default Gateway]

When you upgrade your gateway to one such as this:

[image: Gateway 2 CPU]

You can see there is another slot for another CPU that you can buy.

To actually benefit from this extra slot you have to buy another CPU. To see the different upgrades you can buy for your gateway, pick the "Hardware upgrades" option on the Uplink Internal Services menu.

[image: Uplink Internal Services Menu]

Comment: * only exception is the remote access gateway which provides some safety from traces without additional purchases.

Comment: @kotekzot I've never played Onlink. Uplink definitely has a Gateway with a wireless connection to the modem, so if you get traced they can't find your gateway. It doesn't protect you from a bank job trace to your account, however.

Comment: @Nick i've just checked and you're right, there is a remote access terminal. I never paid much attention to it because it is quite poor in other departments.